# Using ehcache in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

do you have any experience with using ehcache within Apache Camel context?

I need to load some config data from database during initialiation of a camel context and store them in ehcache.

Comment: What did you try? Did you write some code?

Comment: I used camel-cache component and RoutePolicy.init method.

Answer (score 0):

EHCache is the default cache implementation of camel. All you have to do is to use the "cache" component of camel (in camel-cache jar).